# Align text in itemize to the right inside a table

Tags: tables, itemize

I have this code

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.3\textwidth}}
 \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt]
  \item 1
  \item 2
 \end{itemize}&
 \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, label={}]
  \item 1
  \item 2
 \end{itemize}&
 \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, label={}]
  \item 1
  \item 2
 \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
```

which basically works. However, I would like the items of the last `itemize` to be flushed to the right, so the text appears at the end of the line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you looking for the following:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

That align of cells contents is easier to see, to table are added horizontal and vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}|p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}
                   |p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth} 
                   |p{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}|@{}}
    \hline
 \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt]
  \item 1
  \item 2
 \end{itemize}  &
 \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, label={}]
  \item 1
  \item 2
 \end{itemize}  &
 \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt, wide, label={}]\raggedleft % <---
  \item 1
  \item \large longer item here in two lines?
  \item some short
 \end{itemize}  \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In case, that you not like lines in table, just delete them and correct table set up to:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
                   p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} 
                   p{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
```

**Edit:**

- Each cell is constituted by `\tabcolsep`, width of text and `\tabcolsep`.
- `@{}` remove `\tabcolsep`. This means, that in the your case at first column in the cell construction is remove the first `\tabcolsep` and at the last the second one.
- In the column type `p{<width>` is with `<width>` defined width of a text in the cell. Consequently, the width of column is equal `<width> + 2\tabcolsep` if there is no `@{}`.
- That table can be fit in text area, the sum of column widths should be equal to `\textwidth`. That means that in your case at column specification `{@{} p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.3\linewidth} p {0.2\linewidth} @{}}` table will spill out of text area for

  `\tabcolsep` (from the first column) + `2\tabcolsep` (from the second column) + `tabcolsep` (from the last column).

  That this will not happen, the  in column specification should be reduced accordingly. This can be simply done by use of the TeX primitive `\dimexpr` (intended for calculation of lengths), by which is calculated width of columns.
- In the first version of answer I made mistake in the calculation which is now corrected
- In the above MWE, as has been already mentioned, are added vertical lines, that is simpler to see positioning of lists in cells. If you remove them, as described in original answer, table will looks as follows

[image]

Comment: Great. That basically worked, but the numbers in the last column are not exactly at the end of the line, as if I used `\hfill` to push the text to the end of the line when I don't use `tabular`. Could you please add some explanation of what the options mean (`\dimexpr`, `\tabcolsep`), and why `\tabcolsep` is multiplied by 2? Also what `@{}` means at the beginning and the end? The table spans the `\textwidth` which is the page width minus the margins. There is nothing to the right of the table as you showed in the layout

Comment: @BlackMath, partly you are right. Only at middle column width should be reduced for `ˇ2\tabcolsep`, meanwhile the first and the last with just `\tabcolsep`. See added explanation in answer.